# Is there a way to reuse a reducer logic in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reusability, reducers

I am using react/redux to build my app. There are multiple buttons and the app needs to keep track of states of whether these buttons were clicked. These buttons are all using the same reducer logic, which is to alternate the state from true to false whenever the button is clicked. The only differentiator is the name of the state. Is there a way to reduce my code by defining a "global" reducer that can be applied to multiple states? Please refer to this image for an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKtVP.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Instead of dispatching unique action for every button type like `MENU_BTN`, `SEARCH_BTN`, etc.. I would dispatch `{ type: 'TOGGLE_BUTTON', payload: 'menu' }` and in reducer

```
case TOGGLE_BUTTON:
  return {
    [payload]: !state[payload]
    ...state
  }
```

You can then toggle buttons like this

```
const toggleButton = key => ({
  type: 'TOGGLE_BUTTON',
  payload: key
})
dispatch(toggleButton('menu'))
dispatch(toggleButton('search'))
```

That way you can keep track of as many buttons as you want. Your state will then look something like this

```
...
buttons: {
  menu: true,
  search: false
}
...
```

and you can easily write selector for every button

```
// Component displaying state of menu button //
let MyComponent = ({ menuButtonState }) => (
  <div>
  Menu button is {menuButtonState ? 'on' : 'off'}
  </div>
)
// Helper function for creating selectors //
const createGetIsButtonToggledSelector = key => state => !!state.buttons[key]
// Selector getting state of a menu button from store //
const getIsMenuButtonToggled = createGetIsButtonToggledSelector('menu')
// Connecting MyComponent to menu button state //
MyComponent = connect(state => ({
  menuButtonState: getIsMenuButtonToggled(state)
})(MyComponent)
```

Comment: This was really helpful! It would be even more helpful if you could elaborate on the selector section! Thanks!!

Comment: I added some comments, read some introduction to selectors on internet and it should start making more sense. You are basically trying  to get some value from store to your components props and common practice is to use selectors for that. You can then read about library called `reselect` which makes getting values from store more performant.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **generic higher-order reducer** that accepts both a given reducer function and a name or identifier.

```js
function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function createNamedWrapperReducer(reducerFunction, reducerName) {
  return (state, action) => {
    const { name } = action
    const isInitializationCall = state === undefined
    if (name !== reducerName && !isInitializationCall) return state

    return reducerFunction(state, action)
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  counterA: createNamedWrapperReducer(counter, 'A'),
  counterB: createNamedWrapperReducer(counter, 'B'),
  counterC: createNamedWrapperReducer(counter, 'C')
})
```

The above **createdNamedWrapperReducer()** method should work out of the box.

See [Redux's recipes for Reusing Reducer Logic](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic) for a more detailed explanation or more examples.